# Using DataFrame in barplot

Tags: r

Having the following `df`:

```
Year Qty
2005 400
2006 555
2007 234
...
```

How can I use this in a `barplot`?
Tried this but it didn't work

```
barplot(df1,xlab="Quantity",ylab="Year",main="foo")
'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a named vector

```
barplot(setNames(df$Qty, df$Year), xlab="Year", ylab="Quantity", main="foo")
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 2005:2007, Qty = c(400L, 555L, 234L)),
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

-plot

[image]